# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL slow

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsdata

I have some performance problem with NSData dataWithContentsOfURL...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Imagepath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
[ArrayImages addObject:img];
```

This code is placed in a method that manage a JSON response got from an NSUrl connection(after calling my web service). All the code in this method is already in a background thread, moving this piece of code out the background thread do not solve the issue.. All the retrieved image are placed in a view in main thread. What i can do to make dataWithContentsOfURL faster or there is a alternative to dataWithContentsOfURL?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

`+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` is not "slow". If loading one image takes a long time, the problem lies elsewhere.

---

Evaluate your problem. For starters:

- Which resource is the bottleneck? Probably the Network.
- How do you load images? All at once? That would be bad -- display them as they become ready.
- What are the sizes of the images? I saw one SO question where the poster wanted to load **50 MB** images. That's way too large. As well, if all you need is a thumbnail, then be sure you request the thumbnail from the server and load that and not the full-sized image.
- Are you loading things you don't even need to display? Wait until you need to display them.
- How many threads are you using for Network tasks? For CPU? For I/O?
- Are your source images properly "crushed"?
- Write your program so it flows with your program's presentation model. Example: I had a bazillion images to display in tables, but I made sure to minimize resource usage and made sure load and request cancellation was well supported for the app. This was all coming through the network, and it was plenty fast (it was network-bound).

and if you are loading many images from device storage, you should consider using `-[UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:]` instead because your image data would not be cached, but can be purged.

Comment: hi, i load thumb images , maximum 50 thumb for a weight of 2k each image. I don't load things that i don't need to display. I'm using the main thread to launch the connection e to recive the json string, but i work with the json string in another background method (the same method where the code i posted is placed). I create in this way an array of images that will be cycled in - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

Comment: I have tried to insert directly the image in the custom makannotationview,without the array,but the result is the same. What do you mean with "crushed"?

Comment: @Cri1682 lossless image compressors, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush they can reduce your network and i/o greatly.

Answer (score 0):

U  need to use Lazy loading for images display as content will displayed as image gets downloaded.

Use  [SDWebImage which uses lazy loading of images](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: thanks but i think sdwebimage doesn't solve the issue. nsdata datawithcontentsofUrl it's slow even i don't insert uiimage in any uiimageview. I think it isn't a "visualization" problem

Comment: intially it will take some time for json response. Afterwards image web url link can be lazy loaded in app